# MvvmCross + Azure Mobile Services example

Tags: azure, xamarin, mvvmcross, azure-mobile-services

It seems one cannot add the Azure Mobile Services NuGet package to a "Project.Core" of a MvvmCross project that targets IOS, Android, Windows Phone and Windows Store. It is not a PCL library it seems. What's the alternative? Define a Service interface in the "Core" project, that gets implemented on each subsequent platform?

Anyone has a working example of this, or other alternative?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

MvvmCross has something called Plugins, which consists of multiple parts:

- Core PCL project, where you define Interfaces, which you will be able to use in other PCL projects
- Platform specific projects, which implement the Interfaces.

There are loads of plugins you can look at how are implemented here:
https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/tree/v3.1/Plugins

There is documentation about how plugins work here:
https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/MvvmCross-plugins